# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Tags: php, html, mysql

посмотрел для этого кода нет ответа и он очень уж странный:

```
 $status=$_POST["status"];
if($status=="del")
{ $id=$_POST["id"];
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM wel_xak WHERE id='$id'");
 echo "<br><center>Çàïèñü óäàëåíà</center>";
}

echo <<<HTML
<center><br><br><table width=600 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<th width=20 align=center>¹id</th>
<th width=100 align=center>username</th>
<th width=150 align=center>ip Ïîëüçîâàòåëÿ</th>
<th width=130 align=center>Äàòà</th>
<th width=100 align=center>Óäàëèòü</th>
</tr>
HTML;

$res = mysql_query("SELECT  FROM wel_xak ORDER BY id ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {echo <<<HTML
<tr>
<td>{$row['id']}</td>
<td>{$row['username']}</td>
<td>{$row['ipadres']}</td>
<td>{$row['data']}</td>
<td>
<form method="post" action="adminmain.php?p=welxak">
<input name="status" type="hidden" value="del">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="{$row['id']}">
<input type="submit" value="Óäàëèòü" class="button">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас запрос неправильный, нужно так:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wel_xak ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/u392648506/public_html/vacha-adminka/welxak.php on line 38

Comment: <? include('checkcookie.php');

$status=$_POST["status"];
if($status=="del")
{ $id=$_POST["id"];
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM wel_xak WHERE id='$id'");
 echo "<br><center>Çàïèñü óäàëåíà</center>";
}

Comment: }

echo <<<HTML
<center><br><br><table width=600 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<th width=20 align=center>id</th>
<th width=100 align=center>username</th>
<th width=150 align=center>ip Ïîëüçîâàòåëÿ</th>
<th width=130 align=center>Äàòà</th>
<th width=100 align=center>Óäàëèòü</th>
</tr>
HTML>>>;

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wel_xak ORDER BY id ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {echo <<<HTML

Comment: <tr>
<td>{$row['id']}</td>
<td>{$row['username']}</td>
<td>{$row['ipadres']}</td>
<td>{$row['data']}</td>
<td>
<form method="post" action="adminmain.php?p=welxak">
<input name="status" type="hidden" value="del">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="{$row['id']}">
<input type="submit" value="Óäàëèòü" class="button">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<<<HTML;
}
?>

Comment: ВСЁ РАВНО ОШИБКИ

Comment: Я вам дал решение вашей ошибки. То, о чем вы написали `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/u392648506/public_html/vacha-adminka/welxak.php on line 38`, не из-за этого кода.